# Zarr: improve xarray writing performance to S3

Tags: python, python-xarray, zarr, python-s3fs

Writing `xarray` datasets to AWS S3 takes a surprisingly big amount of time, even when no data is actually written with `compute=False`.

Here's an example:

```py
import fsspec
import xarray as xr

x = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("rasm")
target = fsspec.get_mapper("s3://bucket/target.zarr")
task = x.to_zarr(target, compute=False)
```

Even without actually computing it, `to_zarr` takes **around 6 seconds** from an EC2 that's in the same region as the S3 bucket.

Looking at the debug logs, there seems to be quite a bit of redirecting going on, as the default region in `aiobotocore` is set to `us-east-2` while the bucket is in `eu-central-1`.

If I first manually put the default region into the environment variables with

```py
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'eu-central-1'
```

then the required time drops to **around 3.5 seconds**.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any way to pass the region to `fsspec` (or `s3fs`)? I've tried adding `s3_additional_kwargs={"region":"eu-central-1"}` to the `get_mapper` method, but that didn't do anything.
2. Is there any better way to interface with zarr on S3 from `xarray` than the above (with `fsspec`)?

---

versions:

```
xarray: 0.17.0
zarr: 2.6.1
fsspec: 0.8.4
```

Comment: You might take a look at https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2300#issuecomment-805883595 "zarr and xarray chunking compatibility and to_zarr performance"

Comment: @Josh thanks, but I don't think this is a chunk issue

Comment: @Val As per the [s3fs documentation](https://github.com/dask/s3fs/blob/7d80c3198923cc6016b67bd8e857642a17f4f7e5/s3fs/core.py#L619) they show `region_name` as a kwargs and also the fsspec issue regarding using the [region](https://github.com/intake/filesystem_spec/issues/386#issuecomment-683787104). However zarr is widely popular for huge dataset. Unfortunately, I don't have current tools to verify the above links

Comment: @NagarajTantri setting `client_kwargs={'region_name':'eu-central-1'}` does the trick and answers point #1. If you want, please post an answer I can accept. Thanks!

Comment: Done, @Val. Do check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While checking their documentation, for [s3fs documentation](https://github.com/dask/s3fs/blob/7d80c3198923cc6016b67bd8e857642a17f4f7e5/s3fs/core.py#L619) they show `region_name` as a `kwargs` and also the fsspec issue regarding using the [region](https://github.com/intake/filesystem_spec/issues/386#issuecomment-683787104)

So you can use something like `client_kwargs={'region_name':'eu-central-1'}` in the `get_mapper`, like:

```
fsspec.get_mapper("s3://bucket/target.zarr", 
                  client_kwargs={'region_name':'eu-central-1'})
```

Also, `zarr` is widely popular for a huge dataset.